# How to set fixed column width in tabulate module of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, col, tabulate

How to set fixed column width in tabulate module of python

eg:

```
table_header = ['CURRENT TIME', 'NAMESPACE', 'CPU REQUESTS', 'CPU LIMITS', 'MEMORY REQUESTS', 'MEMORY LIMITS']
with open("abc.txt", 'a') as txt_file:
    txt_file.write(tabulate([table_header], headers='firstrow', tablefmt='grid', stralign=('center', 'center', 'center', 'center', 'center', 'center')) + '\n')
```

The header and the data are not aligned properly due to difference in column width.

Comment: The whole point of using tabulate is that you pass the headers and data in all at the same time & it automatically determines whitespace. If you want a fixed width, just use f-strings.

Comment: But I am using it in iterations. So I need to pass the header  separately, and then pass the data in iterations.

Comment: You will need to evaluate the data associated with the headers to find the maximum width. You can't write the headers to the file then expect "magic" to happen when you start writing the data